# Why do I get an Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a gambling game and I am trying that when you hit the button the blue.png turns into the green.png but it tells me that I have an Unchaught TypeError. It is also giving me an error at the onclick, is there a way to take this away? I know that onclick works on images so I don't know why it doesn't work on buttons, is there another property that will do about the same thing?

```js
let tokens = 100
let left = 1
let middle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
document.getElementById("tokens").innerHTML = formatTokens(tokens);

function formatTokens(num, digits = 1) {
  var si = [{
      value: 1,
      symbol: ""
    },
    {
      value: 1E3,
      symbol: " K"
    },
    {
      value: 1E6,
      symbol: " Million"
    },
    {
      value: 1E9,
      symbol: " Billion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E12,
      symbol: " trillion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E15,
      symbol: " Quadrillion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E18,
      symbol: " Quintillion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E18,
      symbol: " Quintillion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E21,
      symbol: " Sextillion"
    }
  ];
  var rx = /\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/;
  var i;
  for (i = si.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (num >= si[i].value) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return (num / si[i].value).toFixed(digits).replace(rx, "$1") + si[i].symbol;
}


function gamble() {
  if (left == 1) {
    document.getElementById("green.png").innerHTML = "<img src='green.png' />";
    console.log("hi")
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sectionLeft">
    <center>
      <div class="tokenshower">
        <span id="tokens">100</span> Tokens<br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input type="number" size="100">
      
      <div class="leftdiamond">
        <img src="blue.png" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="middlediamond">
        <img src="red.png" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="rightdiamond">
        <img src="green.png" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <button onclick="gamble()" height="1000000px" width=2 00px>daddy</button>
      <img id="blue" src="blue.png">
</body>
```

Comment: Unrelated protips: The `center` element is deprecated. Don't use it. (Also, you didn't close the element.) Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not what they're for. Use margin or padding.

Answer (score 1):

You're using getElementById but there is no id set. Try setting an id for the img. Example:

`<img src="green.png" id="green" width="100" height="100">`

Answer (score 0):

You could add an ID to that element, which doesn't have one. `getElementById` can't work otherwise.

Or, if you don't want to do that, select for the `src` attribute and value:

```
querySelector('[src="green.png"]')
```

This will return the *first* element with that attribute value.

```js
let tokens = 100
let left = 1
let middle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
document.getElementById("tokens").innerHTML = formatTokens(tokens);

function formatTokens(num, digits = 1) {
  var si = [{
      value: 1,
      symbol: ""
    },
    {
      value: 1E3,
      symbol: " K"
    },
    {
      value: 1E6,
      symbol: " Million"
    },
    {
      value: 1E9,
      symbol: " Billion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E12,
      symbol: " trillion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E15,
      symbol: " Quadrillion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E18,
      symbol: " Quintillion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E18,
      symbol: " Quintillion"
    },
    {
      value: 1E21,
      symbol: " Sextillion"
    }
  ];
  var rx = /\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/;
  var i;
  for (i = si.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (num >= si[i].value) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return (num / si[i].value).toFixed(digits).replace(rx, "$1") + si[i].symbol;
}


function gamble() {
  if (left == 1) {
    document.querySelector('[src="green.png"]').innerHTML = "<img src='green.png' />";
    console.log("hi")
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sectionLeft">
    <center>
      <div class="tokenshower">
        <span id="tokens">100</span> Tokens<br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <input type="number" size="100">
      
      <div class="leftdiamond">
        <img src="blue.png" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="middlediamond">
        <img src="red.png" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <div class="rightdiamond">
        <img src="green.png" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
      
      <button onclick="gamble()" height="1000000px" width=2 00px>daddy</button>
      <img id="blue" src="blue.png">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script must run *AFTER* the "tokens" element loads. This can be done either by registering an `onload` handler to `window`, or put the script after the element.